# Import package in python module that has main function

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to reuse a package that I have written in a new project and I am currently having problems with imports. 
I recreated a minimal example that shows the problem. The folder structure is as following:

```
test\
    __init__.py
    main.py
    package\
        __init__.py
        p1.py
        p2.py
```

The problem stems from the fact that p1 imports p2

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("P1",__name__,__package__)

import p2

def a():
    p2.b()
    print("A")

if __name__=="__main__":
    a()
    p2.b()
```

And this is the main.py code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("MAIN",__name__,__package__)
from package.p1 import a
from package.p2 import b

if __name__=="__main__":
    a()
    b()
```

and here is p2.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("P2",__name__,__package__)

def b():
    print("B")

if __name__=="__main__":
    b()
```

When running main.py I get a `ImportError: No module named p2`

I can fix this according to the modules [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) by changing the import in p1:

> Since the name of the main module is always "**main**", modules
>   intended for use as the main module of a Python application should
>   always use absolute imports.

My understanding of this sentence is that I should change the import in p1 to `from package import p2`. However this breaks p1:

```
ImportError: No module named package
```

I've found other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path/6098238#6098238) that just suggest to modify sys.path explicitly adding folders but that does not seem clean to me. What am I missing? What is the pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Try to change `p1` to do `from . import p2`

Comment: ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: Is your `package/__init__.py` empty (or does it exist at all)?

Comment: __init__.py exists in every folder and it is empty.